# Getting error on Azure Web App using "Microsoft Office Document Imaging"

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, modi

I'm developing an **ASP.net web api (.NET Framework)** and use "Microsoft Office Document Imaging" v12. 
On my local system, it works fine. But then I pushed it on my azure web app and I got following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MODI, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I'm sure, I have to install **"Microsoft Office Document Imaging"**. But how can I do this when I'm just using an **Azure Web App**?

---

**EDIT:** I found a much better way to solve my problem: https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we don't have permission to install the "Microsoft Office Document Imaging"(using sharepoint install package) in the azure web app.

Azure web app env as a sanbox, there are several strict restrictions and limitations, we couldn't use it as azure VM. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

If you still want to use "Microsoft Office Document Imaging", I suggest you could consider using azure VM which we have full permission to change the env.

Besides,I guess you wan to convert the doc to image. I suggest you could try to use [Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/) to convert the doc to image or PDF.

This package could be installed in the Nuget Package.

More details, you could refer to below test demo codes.

```
        string location = Server.MapPath("/exe/");
        Document document = new Document(Server.MapPath("/exe/bbbb.docx"));
        ImageSaveOptions options = new ImageSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Png);
        options.PageCount = 1;

        // Save each page of the document as Png.
        for (int i = 0; i < document.PageCount; i++)
        {
            options.PageIndex = i;
            document.Save(string.Format(location+ @"\out_{0}.png", i), options);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm using the MODI to extract the words from a document/image.. Is it also possible with Aspose.Words?
I saw there is also Aspose.OCR, but it costs too much for my needs..

Comment: I suggest you could consider using azure VM. As my above azure web app sandbox [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) says, azure web app just support little third party convert tool. So if you used the sadbox not supported tool, you will face the same error.